# Find distance between point on tangent line and circle.

Tags: trigonometry

Given a circle with radius r, and a tangent line segment with length a.
The midpoint of line a is the point of tangency.

Find the length of line segment b.

I am trying to figure out an equation to solve for the length of b.  I'm using javascript, but I can adapt general equations.  thanks.

[image]

Comment: More information about the tangent line segment is needed. Is the point of tangency also the midpoint of the segment?

Comment: @RoryDaulton Yes, that is correct.  The midpoint of line a is the point of tangency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pytagorean theorem, 
$$
\biggl(\dfrac{a}{2}\biggr)^2 + (r - b)^2 = r^2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad b = r -\sqrt{r^2 - a^2/4}
$$ 
if $a \leq 2r$.

Comment: awesome, thanks.  the javascript function for this is  `b = r - Math.sqrt(r*r-a*a/4)`

Answer (score 1):

Join the the end-point say B of the line segment $b$ to the center say O  of circle & drop a perpendicular say BN from end-point  B of line segment b to the x-axis we get a right $\triangle BNO$ $$ON=\sqrt{(OB)^2-(BN)^2}=\sqrt{r^2-\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4r^2-a^2}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2}$$ Hence the length of segment $b$ is given as $$b=r-ON=r-\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2}$$
hence, 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{b=r-\frac{\sqrt{4r^2-a^2}}{2}}}$$